# Why isn't my method to rotate a point around another point working?

Tags: java, rotation, trigonometry

I have a method in my android app that looks like this:

```
//get point after rotation
public static PointF getRotatedPoint(PointF pt,PointF center, float degrees)
{
    double angleInRadians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    pt.x = (float) (Math.cos(angleInRadians) * (pt.x-center.x) - Math.sin(angleInRadians) * (pt.y-center.y) + center.x);
    pt.y = (float) (Math.sin(angleInRadians) * (pt.x-center.x) + Math.cos(angleInRadians) * (pt.y-center.y) + center.y);
    return pt;
}
```

I have a rectangle that I rotate by 45 degrees.  I can touch any point on the rotated rectangle and it gives me the touched point  I want to get the coordinates of the point if the rectangle wasn't rotated.  So I pass in -45 in the degrees argument.  Here is how I call it:

```
getRotatedPoint(touchedPoint, centerOfRectangle,-45);
```

When I draw the point on the rectangle before it gets rotated, it gives me a result close to the position I touched on the rotated rectangle but off by a pretty big difference.

Here is a picture to explain my problem:
[image: explaination]

I think this might be a problem with my math so any answers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18733036/61624

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing initial and final values in the calculations. You re-assign `pt.x`:

```
pt.x = (float) (Math.cos(angleInRadians) * (pt.x-center.x) - Math.sin(angleInRadians) * (pt.y-center.y) + center.x);
```

which doesn't immediately pose any problems. But the calculation for `pt.y` relies on the *original* value of `pt.x`, not the rotated value:

```
pt.y = (float) (Math.sin(angleInRadians) * (pt.x-center.x) + Math.cos(angleInRadians) * (pt.y-center.y) + center.y);
```

Thus just use some temporary variables to hold the initial values.

```
public static PointF getRotatedPoint(PointF pt,PointF center, float degrees)
{
    double x0 = pt.x;
    double y0 = pt.y;
    double angleInRadians = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);
    pt.x = (float) (Math.cos(angleInRadians) * (x0-center.x) - Math.sin(angleInRadians) * (y0-center.y) + center.x);
    pt.y = (float) (Math.sin(angleInRadians) * (x0-center.x) + Math.cos(angleInRadians) * (y0-center.y) + center.y);
    return pt;
}
```